# Email verification new idea

Tags: email, verification

I got a bit different idea about verify email, instead of sending a mail to my client with unique message to verify against my server, I will not send him nothing but ask him to send a mail to me, then I check the sender and the unique message in the mail and verify that email.

Basically the user will click a button a new mail box will open with all the data already filled in, and what he will have to do is to press send.

My question is: First can this work? And second how safe is it in compare to the official way with all its disadvantages. I just want to know if I am not opening any new security risks.

Comment: First I'll ask you do you know PHP ? It's done with PHP very simply.

Comment: Are you sure that you understand my question? I need an implementation of hosting service that can read eMails. If you got an example that implements it in PHP I would more then glade to give it a look

Comment: I think it's insecure and easily circumvented with [Email spoofing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_spoofing). You could argue that it would be possible to protect yourself from that and somehow find out if the email was sent from the correct server - but in the end why is your solution easier or better than the current one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So instead of the standard "please click on this link to confirm your account" you want to offer your user to send a mail upon creation of his account ?

I don't see where your solution is any better than the original one. You'll have to receive tons of mails that you then have to analyse if the information inside is correct. That means that the work to verify an account is only done somewhere else.

original one: you send a url via mail and if its opened you activate the user. The logic can be implemented for example with a simple servlet. You could encrypt the user's database entry in the url and all that's left for the servlet is a simple db lookup.

your one: you receive identification via mail and run your logic over the mail.

However one possible problem is that it's feasible to modify the address a mail was sent from. You could never be sure that there really is a mailaccount behind the mail that was sent to you. Another even more dangerous flaw is that malicious users could spam the mail account you're using. In the original solution any incoming mails can be discarded but you have to store and process them.

Comment: My solution is better simply because sending mails cost money and reading is not... But you do got a point. My mail indeed can be spam with malicious users. How ever I can think about a solution for this. Maybe I will create temporary mail for each user request an close it after first mail received or by timeout.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I see a little usability problem here and another security problem. Let's talk about both in order:

- The classic way of email verification is done especially to validate a user's email address. In others words, to verify that the address the user filled in is his/her real email address. If you want to verify the same thing, you have to 'make your user' to send you an email from his/her real email address. So, you could use an 'email' link type and fill in all you need, but what if the user is at an Internet club or at a public computer. There will be no settings for him. Or what if he wants to send you the mail later? What then? This is a usability problem. Another problem is, that you put users to effectively write a mail (even if you fill in the information) which is  a kind of extra step.
- The security problem. What if a user registers and between registration and email confirmation someone else sends in a mail?

Comment: I will create a database with mailKey and email address, and I ask my users to send me the mailKey. Once I got the key I pull out the mail stored in my db, and compare it to the sender mail, if I got a match I will flag this mail as verified!

Comment: Let's just presume there is a person who want's to harm your future user. He can get that unique key by intercepting the webpage (if not https), or checking user's browser cache, etc. Once you send something over the Internet unencrypted and show it in a browser, it can be a security issue. If you site will not do ultra secret stuff, it may not be a big problem, but it is an extra and unnecessary risk. That's all. You, can, of course, from a technical point of view do it (not with the php mail() function from some answers). I see no reason why the classic way would be any harder to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use mailto: link to start default email application on user's computer because if you will send email from your website you will not know sender address. But what if  user does not have email application installed? For example user uses webmail like Gmail? That would not work in this case.